# SQLite Select Path always return Null

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm trying to select strings like that : `"\\Data\\file - test.md"`

I don't understand why it keeps returning nothing but i can insert in the SQLite

```
public List<String> Select(String Path)
{
    List<String> list = new List<String>();
    using (SQLiteCommand fmd = this.conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        fmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FILE WHERE Path = ?";
        fmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(Path));
        fmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SQLiteDataReader r = fmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (r.HasRows)
        {
            while (r.Read())
            {
                list.Add(r.GetString(0));
                list.Add(r.GetString(1));
                list.Add(r.GetString(2));
            }
        }
        else
        {
           return null;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that i need to use @ for the parameters and not ?

```
public List<String> Select(String Path)
{
    List<String> list = new List<String>();
    using (SQLiteCommand fmd = this.conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        fmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FILE WHERE Path = @path";
        fmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@path", Path));
        fmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SQLiteDataReader r = fmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (r.HasRows)
        {
            while (r.Read())
            {
                list.Add(r.GetString(0));
                list.Add(r.GetString(1));
                list.Add(r.GetString(2));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: In theory, `?` and `@xxx` should behave the same (except that the former has no name).

Comment: Yeah i thought the same but in this case it seems that they don't have the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

If it is returning null, it means the function returns from this part of code

```
else
{
   return null;
}
```

That is else part of `if (r.HasRows)`. It means the connection established and the query executed but no record matched your passed parameter. One reason could be that you are passing a string with escape sequence characters and the parameter value is not what you intend to pass. Please debug and make sure that `Path` variable is not skipping any characters. Like if your search path contains `\` then it should be passed as `\\` to make sure it matches with values in `FILE` that contain this character.

Hope it helps